# How can I remotely unlock my phone with a non-working display?

Tags: lock-screens, android-device-manager, screencast

I have a Samsung S5, model SAMSUNG-SM-G900A. My screen was already fairly damaged and I could not get a replacement yet, and today my phone fell and the screen is now completely black (although the touch keys at the bottom still light up when I press the power button on the side).

I thought I could maybe perform screen mirroring using `Vysor` to at least temporarily have access to my data (authenticators etc.), but unfortunately this requires the phone to be unlocked first.

I took a look at Google's Android Device Manager (where my device was already registered), but did not find an "unlock" option - only lock, ring and erase.

Do I have any options?

To reiterate:

1. The device itself is working, the screen is not.
2. I wish to perform screen mirroring (e.g. on my laptop) using `Vysor` or something similar.
3. I cannot do the above due to the phone being locked.
4. I only need the mirroring to be able to input my pass on my laptop.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you by any chance have USB debugging enabled?

Comment: I have had it enabled at some point, but I am not 100% certain that it is on at the moment.